# Play a wav or mp3 file inside client window

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, content-type

I want to play my wav or mp3 file inside the client window and I'm using this code

```
const head = {
     'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav, audio/wav',
}
res.writeHead(200, head);
res.write(MY_URL);      
res.end();
```

But it doesn't play. When I pass audioContent inside write, it works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: How does the user have access to this link? Should he click on any button or url on the site to be redirected to that page or are you providing the direct link to the page with audio for the user?

Comment: @AksJacoves I give this url to the user inside the app. They have a link. On opening this page, a specific audio should play.